# Rhino.Mocks: method calls recorder (a.k.a. test spy)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have a piece of logic I want to test and it uses dependency injected interface with one (or more) void methods, example:

```
interface IMyService
{
    void MethodA (MyComplexObject arg1, int arg2);
}
```

What I would want is to create a stub for this `IMyService` that would just **record** the method invocations of `MethodA` and I would later be able to access it as a list, something like:

```
MyComplexObject actualParameter = serviceRecorder
    .GetMethodRecordings("MethodA").GetRecord(10).GetInputParameter(0);
```

I need this to examine the contents of such a parameter for a certain invocation and make assertions on it. I know there are other was of doing it (like setting expectation calls with constraints), but this seems much easier to write for cases when you have a lot of invocations and you want to make assertions on the 51th one only, for example.

**So is there some sort of mechanism in Rhino.Mocks for this or am I left to my own devices (writing dummy `IMyService` implementation with recording capabilities)?**

NOTE: (I'm aware this could lead to tests being fragile and I'm aware of the consequences).

UPDATE: here's what I found so far (thanks in part to Mark's help in naming this pattern as Test Spy):

- [Advanced mocking: anonymous test spy](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2008/03/06/advanced-mocking-anonymous-test-spy.aspx)
- Perhaps using Windsor Castle's [interceptors](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/31/Logging--the-AOP-way.aspx)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// arrange
var myServiceStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyService>();
var myComplexObj = new MyComplexObject 
{
    SomeProp = "something",
    SomeOtherProp = "something else"
};

// act
myServiceStub.MethodA(myComplexObj, 10);

// assert
myServiceStub.AssertWasCalled(
    x => x.MethodA(
        Arg<MyComplexObject>.Matches(
            arg1 => arg1.SomeProp == "something" &&
                    arg1.SomeOtherProp == "something else"
        ), 
        Arg<int>.Is.Equal(10)
    )
);
```

Remark: Don't forget to make the interface public or Rhino Mocks won't be able to create a proxy.

---

UPDATE:

Sorry I didn't read your question carefully. Here's how to get the desired behavior:

```
var args = myServiceStub.GetArgumentsForCallsMadeOn(
    x => x.MethodA(null, default(int)),
    x => x.IgnoreArguments()
);

var theComplexObjectPassedAtThe51thCall = (MyComlexObject)args[50][0];
// TODO: assert something on this object
```

Comment: Darin thanks, but this is what I was trying to avoid: complex inline assertion logic. Anyway, how would you do this kind of assertion on a 51st invocation, for example? It can be done, but then the test code becomes bloated. I want to separate the recording out of the actual test code.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Arrange-Act-Assert (AAA) syntax of Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/05/16/Rhino-Mocks--Arrange-Act-Assert-Syntax.aspx).

In overall, the Record-Replay syntax is obsolete. It was fantastic when it was invented, but with the advent of lambda expressions we got something even better.

[Rhino Mocks 4 is probably not going to support Record-Replay](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/09/03/planning-for-rhino-mocks-4.0.aspx), but instead relies on lambda expressions, and so does [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/).

Finally, a Test Double that records invocations for later inspection is called a Test Spy - see [xUnit Test Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131495054) for more information :)

Comment: Mark, I'm already using AAA syntax, but I suspect AAA vs. record-replay is not an issue here - the underlying mocking logic still has the ability to intercept calls.
As for Test Spy: thanks for pointing this out - I haven't yet reached that part of the book :)

Comment: +1 for mentioning both the happy departure of Record-Replay and the excellent Moq library!